# Challenging $\lim_{x \rightarrow 10} \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} = \frac{1}{10}$ for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider the (incorrect) claim that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 10} \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} = \frac{1}{10}.$$

How might I find the largest $\delta$ such that I can challenge $\epsilon = 1/2$?

Clearly I need to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit, but my problem is that I don't know how to find the **largest** delta.

Here is what I know:

- $|f(x) - (1/10)| <1/2$
- $0<|x-10|< \delta$

Comment: I don't know why your question is downvoted but it could be because you didn't use LaTeX. Google StackExchange LaTeX guide to see how to nicely format your math expressions.

Comment: Is my answer along the lines of what you were looking for? I tried to answer in the only reasonable way I saw fit. If it is not what you are looking for, then I think your question needs a great deal more clarification. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking aloud, so your limit $L=\dfrac1{10}$ and your function $f(x)=\dfrac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}$.

$\forall\varepsilon\exists\delta$ etc. So, for $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$, $\exists\delta$ such that if $|x-10|<\delta$ then $\bigl|\dfrac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}-\dfrac1{10}\bigr|<\dfrac12$.

That is $\dfrac{-1}2 + \dfrac1{10}< \dfrac1{\lfloor x\rfloor} < \dfrac12 + \dfrac1{10}$, or equivalently $\dfrac{-4}5< \dfrac1{\lfloor x\rfloor} < \dfrac35$ .

If $x>0$ (or rather when $x\ge1$) then we need $\lfloor x\rfloor>\dfrac53$, so $\lfloor x\rfloor\ge2$.
When $x<0$ we need $\dfrac45> \dfrac{-1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$, so $\dfrac54< -\lfloor x\rfloor$, in turn 
$2\le -\lfloor x\rfloor$, thus $-2\ge \lfloor x\rfloor$, in turn $x<-1$.

How do we ensure that either $\lfloor x\rfloor\ge2$ or $x<-1$, using the single condition $|x-10|<\delta$?
The latter reads as $-\delta+10<x<\delta+10$.
It looks to me we could take $\delta$ as big as $8$, and the condition 
$-\delta+10<x<\delta+10$ becomes $2<x<18$, which implies $\lfloor x\rfloor\ge2$, which implies $\bigl|\dfrac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}-\dfrac1{10}\bigr|<\dfrac12$.
But $\delta$ cannot be bigger than $8$ as then $x<2$ will be allowed, 
but that would entail $\lfloor x\rfloor=1$ (for at least some $x$) but then 
$\bigl|\dfrac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}-\dfrac1{10}\bigr| = 1- \dfrac1{10} = \dfrac9{10}\ge\dfrac12$, which is a problem, not permitted.

So, I would suggest $\delta=8$, post this, and keep reading to see if I have mistakes.

Edit. On second reading I believe $\delta =8$ is naturally related to your question, but I do not understand your question. What would mean for $\delta$ to challenge $\varepsilon$? If I interpret this the only way I am capable of, it seems that my $\delta = 8$ would be the smallest that does not challenge the $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$, and then there is no largest $\delta$ to challenge the $\varepsilon$, for all $\delta>8$ work.

Edit$^2$. Perhaps I wanted to say that $\delta = 8$ would be the  <del>smallest</del> largest that does not challenge the $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$.

Comment: Wonderful!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Any thoughts as to what the largest epsilon might be for which there is no suitable delta possible? Thank you so much, you understood the problem perfectly. Brilliant.

Comment: I am confused and it is too late

Comment: I actually thought along these lines as well at first, but I *think* I know what OP was after now--perhaps. Mind taking a look at my answer and seeing what you think and if it makes any sense at all?

Comment: "Challenge" was the wrong word for me to use and when I wrote this I was interpreting the question incorrectly (although my textbook uses the word challenge). Basically the question meant, say you have an error margin of 1/2. Despite the fact that the limit does not actually equal 1/10, find the largest delta that exists such that the error margin will hold.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is moderately unclear at the moment, I thought I would give you some thoughts that may be helpful in forging ahead.

> How might I find the largest $\delta$ such that I can challenge $\epsilon = 1/2$?

I think this is the *crux* of the problem. What do you mean by "challenge" exactly? This is the part that is currently not clear about your question. First of all, what does $|x-a|$ represent? It represents the *distance* from $x$ to $a$. Hence, the meaning of $0<|x-a|<\delta$ should be clearer now; $\delta$ basically represents "how many units, in either direction, $x$ is permitted to stray from $a$." In your case, $a=1/10$. Now consider the following.

We must contend with 
$$
f(x)=\left|\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}-\frac{1}{10}\right|<\frac{1}{2}.\tag{1}
$$ 
For what $x$-values is $(1)$ true? A graph may help:

[image]

Above, the straight line is the constant value $1/2$ for all $x$-values, and the scattered lines form a plot for your function $f(x)$ in $(1)$. Can you tell from the graph (or algebraically) for which $x$-values $(1)$ holds?

We can see (or reason) that $(1)$ holds true when $x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup[2,\infty)$ but fails if $x\in[-2,2)$. With this in mind, what is the maximum $\delta$-value for which $(1)$ is not true or "challenged"? The maximum value for $\delta$ will be achieved at that point which is farthest from $x=10$. This occurs at $x=-2$, a distance of $12$ units from $x=10$.

Hence, the largest $\delta$ for which you can challenge $\epsilon=1/2$ is $\delta=12$. That is the only reasonable way to answer this question in my opinion.

Comment: @Mirko Ah, how well-timed! haha. Regardless of what happens, OP's question is non-standard. This was the only conceivable thing I could come up with that seemed to make some use of $\delta$ that "messed with" or "challenged" trying to stay within the error tolerance of $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. But who knows? Maybe OP can clarify at some point. Hopefully.

Comment: Say $\delta = 15$. There are some $x$, e.g. in $[-5,-2)$ that are fine, but others in $[-2,2)$ that are not good. So $\delta=15$ does "challenge" $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$ since at allows for some "bad" $x$. So do $\delta=16$, $\delta=17$, etc, so this was my interpretation what there wasn't a largest "bad" $\delta$. In my post I wrote that $\delta=8$ is the smallest that does not challenge $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$, but maybe I should have written that $\delta=8$ is the *largest* that does not challenge $\varepsilon=\dfrac12$ (this way I would agree with the OP at least on the word largest). Whew!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refute existence of limit based on error margin of $ε = \frac{1}{2}$, because the function is indeed close to $\frac{1}{10}$ within that error margin in a suitably small interval around $10$. If you want to disprove the existence of the limit, you need a smaller error margin. Just explicitly calculate what $\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ is when $x \in (9,10)$ and when $x \in (10,11)$ and you will know what error margin you need.

Comment: I am not trying to disprove the claim! I am considering that the claim is true and disproving the given error margin.

Comment: @Carly: I thought you wanted to disprove the claim using that error margin. In any case, what I said still applies. After you calculate what I prescribe, you will see why you can provide a δ that works for that error margin (which is why it wouldn't disprove the existence of limit).